# How to use SAS token Url in HTTP as Status callback - PowerAutomate

Tags: twilio-api, power-automate

I am using PowerAutomate to make a call to Twilio. I use "StatusCallback" and in that I use a URL to another PowerAutomate (Trigger HTTP Request is received) URl. This Url contains the SAS token in the Url.

***Sample Payload parameters***

```
Body: Hi from post!!!
To: +1425******2
From: +1623******4
StatusCallback: https://prod-21.uksouth.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/53edd52****42***432424*****ed48839/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=YP7zZTf*****_H26hZT********8Ytfd*****8
```

The Status callback never gets called. In the Twilio account I can see the error because the Url gets truncated.

I understand why this is getting done, but what i want to know is how to resolve this issue.

Adding a failure that i see on Twilio. It is clearly that the Url Twilio is trying is truncated.
[image]

Comment: If the URL is getting truncated, firstly, how long is it? As a workaround, can you use a URL shortener? Is the statusCallback making a `GET` request or `POST` request? (And if it is `GET` can you change it to `POST` and try again?

Comment: I think it is getting truncated due to the format of the Url. If you check the Status callback Url after "?", the query parameters are seperated by "=" which is treated as not part of the Status Callback but part of some part of overall body. That is the issue

Comment: So did Twilio make a request but to a different URL?

Comment: Yes, the status call back is done but a truncated url (not the full Uri). I have attached the screenshot I see in Twilio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio is actually not displaying your full URL in the log there, but I believe it is making the full request. The issue is not the query parameters in the URL, but the format of the request. You can see in the request inspector the body of the response has an error message:

> The input body for trigger 'manual' of type 'Request' must be of type JSON, but was of type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'.

Your PowerAutomate HTTP trigger expects the HTTP request to be made to be of type JSON, but [Twilio webhooks make HTTP requests in the format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request).

I am finding it difficult to find the documentation on HTTP triggers in PowerAutomate, but if it is possible to change, I would recommend changing the format that the trigger will receive to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If that is not possible, then you will need to translate the original Twilio request into JSON format before sending it to your trigger. You could achieve this with a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/functions). Something like this could work:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  const data = { ...event };
  data.request = undefined;

  await axios.post(context.URL, data) 

  callback(null, new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse());
}
```

This would take all the data sent in to the webhook, turn it into JSON data and POST it to your trigger (saved as an environment variable called `URL` in this case). There is more on [how to write Twilio Functions here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/api-request#code-making-a-write-request-using-x-www-form-urlencoded-format).

Comment: I think it is truncating. If you see my initial post, i have mentioned the Sample Payload and the screenshot shows what is getting called. If you see everything after ?/invoke...." all is truncated. I took the Url in the payload and executed directly from Postman (Full url with data after "/invoke...." and it works

Comment: We’re you sending that as a JSON request in postman?

Comment: No Body Simply this. Below is the code in Postman (converted to Jquery): 

    var settings = {
      "url": "https://prod-21.uksouth.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/53edd52674928ryhf82c0d134324d48839/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=YP7zZTfM30Viw_H26hZTJSxOAFjkEF8YtfdXxOoAPp8",
      "method": "POST",
      "timeout": 0,
    };
    
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });

Comment: But the error from your screenshot in the question says that it expected the body to be JSON, which implies it received a body but couldn’t parse it. So could you try my suggestion?

Comment: I can try that, but I am trying to understand the flow here. The Function I create, would I specify the URL as Status callback in the payload ? I am trying to understand how would this work ?

Comment: Also i get this error: {"message":"Cannot find module 'axios'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handlers/ZN0c3ce57e1eae1d5166bf23cfe91b09fb.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js\n- /var/task/runtime-handler.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Cannot find module 'axios'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handlers/ZN0c3ce57e1eae1d5166bf23cfe91b09fb.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js\n- /var/task/runtime-handler.js\

Comment: Can you add axios to the dependencies and try again. The flow would be to replace your previous stats callback with this function, the function is turning the request from form encoded to JSON so that it’s accepted by power automate.

Comment: It worked after adding dependency of axios